# Extjs's Window, Can't Show Again

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm studying with Extjs4.

I made Ext.window.Window, and use show() Method.

And, I closed Window, and Again use show() Method, That Can't View.

In a word,The Window, Can NOT show again..

What can I do for this Problem?

Sorry to My fool English..

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Window by default is set up to be destroyed on close. To change this behavior set [closeAction](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-closeAction) to `'hide'`:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
  closeAction: 'hide',
  // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

did you check at sencha documentation http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window ?

maybe this link can help you :
http://www.developersnippets.com/2009/07/08/show-or-hide-of-extwindow-panel-with-close-button-inside/